# get the pointer value for AVURLAsset, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in iPhone. I want to get data from AVURLAsset format.

following is my AVURLAsset response.

```
<AVURLAsset: 0x1768c800, URL = http://s9.voscast.com:7924/;.mp3>
```

i can get URL by following code.

```
 AVPlayerItem *item = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
    if(item.status != AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
        return;

    if(item.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
    {
          AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)item.asset;
        NSLog(@"myasset:%@",asset);
        NSString *myurl = [asset valueForKey:@"URL"];
        NSLog(@"myurl:%@",myurl);


    }
```

output of above code is

```
    myasset:<AVURLAsset: 0x1768c800, URL = http://s9.voscast.com:7924/;.mp3>
2015-04-15 23:01:50.452 myurl:http://s9.voscast.com:7924/;.mp3
```

but I want to get **0x1768c800**

can anybody help me how to get above value.

Comment: Use the `%p` format specifier instead of `%@`.

Comment: ya get 0x1768c800 by %p but i want to get value from that object for AVAssetTrack...

Comment: AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]; I have used this code for track but my app is crash because empty array. And asset is also return the value not empty so please help me how to get AVAssetTrack value....

Comment: Your question says nothing about wanting to get the asset track. Your question simply states that you want to get the pointer value for `asset`. You should update your question to make your goal clearer.